# Passing link parameter

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have created a  report having a pie chart and I want to open another report when user clicks on a section of a pie chart. Each section will have two different parameters that will be used in another report (that will be opened when user clicks on pie chart).

I have done lot of R&D on hyperlink and link parameter but not succeeded, although hyperlink is working but not able to get link parameters.

I am using *iReport 4.7.0* and not using *JR Server*.

So how can I set and get link parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Chart Data > Details > Section hyperlink you'd need to set the hyperlink type to `Reference` (`ReportExecution` is JasperReports Server specific).

As hyperlink reference you then can add the link expression e.g.

```
"http://link/to/report?category=" + $F{category} + "&param2=" + $P{param}
```

whereby `$F{category}` is a placeholder for the field that the category of the segment in the pie chart and `$P{param}` is a placeholder for an arbitrary second parameter.

Comment: how do you mean "get this parameter in second report"?

Comment: second report is that which i am going to refer through hyperlink in first report. So how can i use this parameter in second report's query ?

Comment: the second report needs to have a parameter defined with name centerCode. in the query you can use it e.g. as `select .. where <field>=$P{centerCode}`.

Comment: mam, i have already defined that parameter, $P{centerCode}, in second report.  but i am getting null value in it. one issue may be - default value expression for the parameter ?? i haven't given any value in default value expression.

Comment: you mentioned that you are not using JasperReports Server but a custom web application. This application would be responsible to take the URL parameter and pass it to the report.